# Check for internet connection returns wrong results

Tags: react-native

I am trying to check whether the user is connected to internet. I am using NetInfo like this (from the documentation):

```
componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleConnectionChange);

    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(
      (isConnected) => { this.setState({ status: isConnected }); }
    );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('change', this.handleConnectionChange);
}

handleConnectionChange = (isConnected) => {
        this.setState({ status: isConnected });
        console.log(`is connected: ${this.state.status}`);
}
```

The strange is that the first time loading the screen where I am doing this is working fine. But when I start turning on/of my wifi the results are different: sometimes it detects the change sometime no. Someone having the same issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, the iOS simulator doesn't 'notice' when the internet connection is re-connected when using the React Native NetInfo class.

It is rather annoying. However, for me it works as intended on a real device.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I will test on a real device.

Comment: Yes, it's working properly on a device. Thank you so much!

Comment: The same logic without changing anything is not working on Android (device). If I stop the internet and turn it on it's working but it's not working the first time showing the screen.